# Mongoose - Cast to ObjectId failed

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am working on a small blog app and I am stuck here at this error-

```
{
  "message": "Cast to ObjectId failed for value \" 597c4ce202ca9c353fc80e8a\" at path \"_id\" for model \"Blog\"",
  "name": "CastError",
  "stringValue": "\" 597c4ce202ca9c353fc80e8a\"",
  "kind": "ObjectId",
  "value": " 597c4ce202ca9c353fc80e8a",
  "path": "_id"
}
```

I am using findById -
Here is the code

```
app.get("/blogs/:id", function(req, res) {
    Blog.findById(req.params.id, function(err, foundBlog) {
        if (err) {
            res.send(err);
        } else {
            res.render("show", {
                blog: foundBlog
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Here is the app.js file

```
const bodyParser = require('body-parser'),
mongoose         = require('mongoose'),
express          = require('express'),
app              = express();

//APP CONFIG
mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost/blog_rest");
app.set("view engine", "ejs");
app.use(express.static("public"));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true}));

//MONGOOS MODEL CONFIG
var blogSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  title: String,
  image: String,
  body: String,
  created: { type: Date, default: Date.now}
})

var Blog = mongoose.model("Blog", blogSchema);

// Blog.create({
//   title: "TEST BLOG",
//   image: "https://images.pexels.com/photos/457443/pexels-photo-457443.jpeg?h=350&auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb",
//   body: "First App in the series"
// })

//RESTFUL ROUTES
app.get("/", function (req,res) {
  res.redirect("/blogs");
});

//INDEX ROUTE
app.get("/blogs", function (req,res) {
  Blog.find({}, function (err,blogs) {
    if(err){
      // res.send("ERROR");
      console.log(err);
    }
    else {
      res.render("index", {blogs: blogs});
    }
  })
});

//NEW ROUTE
app.get("/blogs/new", function (req,res) {
  res.render("new");
});

//CREATE ROUTE
app.post("/blogs", function (req,res) {
  //Create Blog///////Blog.create takes two parameters first is the data which is in req.body.blog and second is the callback function
  Blog.create(req.body.blog, function (err, newBlog) {
    if (err) {
      res.render("new");
    }
    else {
      res.redirect("/blogs");
    }
  });
});

//SHOW ROUTE
app.get("/blogs/:id", function (req,res) {
  //String.prototype.trim(req.params.id);
  console.log(req.params.id);
  Blog.findById(req.params.id, function (err,foundBlog) {
    if (err) {
      res.send(err);
    } else {
      res.render("show", {blog: foundBlog});
    }
  });
});




app.listen(5000, function () {
  console.log("Server is listening on Port: 5000");
});
```

here is new.ejs:

```
<% include ./partials/header %>

<div class="ui main text container segment">
    <div class="ui huge header">New Blog</div>
    <form class="ui form" action="/blogs" method="post">
        <div class="field">
            <label>Title</label>
            <input type="text" name="blog[title]" placeholder="Title">
        </div>
        <div class="field">
            <label>Image</label>
            <input type="text" name="blog[image]" placeholder="Image">
        </div>
        <div class="field">
            <label>Blog Content</label>
            <textarea name="blog[body]"></textarea>
        </div>
        <input class="ui blue inverted button" type="submit">
    </form>
</div>

<% include ./partials/footer %>
```

and here is show.ejs

```
<div class="ui main text container segment">
    <div class="ui huge header"><%= blog.title %></div>
</div>

<% include ./partials/footer %>
```

After console.log, i got the right id but it has a space in the beginning like this

- ' 597c4ce202ca9c353fc80e8a' and in the url %20 adds up everytime before the id, like this -> http://localhost:5000/blogs/%20597c4ce202ca9c353fc80e8a and if i remove %20 from url then the requested page shows up. 
  I am stuck here for a long time and i have not find solution. please help

Comment: [`String.prototype.trim()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/trim). It removes "whitespace", which is what you have at the beginning of the value in the URL. Probably because of an error in the template where you are reading the link value from. Fix it in one of the places.

Comment: trim your id using str.trim() to remove whitespaces

Comment: i used  
     
String.prototype.trim(req.params.id); but still same error

Comment: could you post the client-side code that makes the request?

Comment: @JamshidAsadzadeh, i have added all the necessary files

Comment: I still can not find where you navigate to your "show" page

Comment: res.render("show",{blog: foundBlog}); is rendring the show page, see the show route

Comment: Hey @NeilLunn and , thanks for your help.    str.trim() solved my problem.

Comment: @Kamesh Thanks to you also.

Answer (score 0):

It feels like ObjectId is not valid. That you are passing.
please check it with :

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.Types.ObjectId.isValid('your id here');
```

Comment: getting same error after this, please understand my question and help me  am just stuck here.

Comment: try with findOne({_id: 'yourIdHere'});

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify into your model that your "id" is of type ObjectId, like below example:

```
const Schema = new mongoose.Schema({
    _id: ObjectID,
    ....
})
```

This should solve the issue!